# Selectize.js multi-select-list option drop-down list closes when the drop-down list's scrollbar is clicked

Tags: drop-down-menu, selectize.js

I have a list with lots of options that is long enough to display a scrollbar when it is opened.

When I try to click on the knob in the options drop-down list scrollbar in order to drag the list (so that I can see other options), the drop-down list closes.

What is the `Selectize.js` configuration setting that I need to set that allows me to scroll the options drop-down list?

Comment: Minor wording changes for readability

Comment: Based on your [codepen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/aazWwY), it looks like you may have already resolved this issue unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: benvc, it turns out that the problem is a conflict between click-handlers in selectize and the page that I'm using it in.  The reason that the CodePen works is that there is nothing else in the CodePen except for the selectized list.  In my web-app the problem still occurs. Do you have an suggestions on I can locate what click-handler is 'stealing' the focus from my selectize list?  I've tried using the global mouse click event tool in Chrome, but I didn't find the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this sounds like one of those roll up your sleeves and start digging kind of things. If you are able to isolate a reasonably small bit of offending code that you can't quite fix, feel free to post another question.

Comment: Thanks, you're so right.  I found that there is a conflict between selectize and jQuery-UI Library Draggable component.  The draggable component is assigned to a Div element that encloses fields in my pop-up form, including the selectized list.  Commenting-out the draggable assignment allows the selectized list to work, but the form is no longer movable.  In the assignment I use the handle feature to limit the draggable function to the form's title area, $( '#songData' ).draggable( { handle : '#songDataTitle' } ), which doen't enclose the selectized list.

Comment: Here is the link to the CodePen: https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/aazWwY

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Found!**

**Symptom:** It turns out that there is a conflict between the selectized.js plug-in and the jQuery-UI Draggability component.

While the CodePen demo works fine, the problem still occurs in my web-app.  One of the many differences in the simple CodePen demo and my web-app is the use of the jQuery-UI Draggability component in the web-app.

**Proof:** With the draggability component attached to the div that encloses the pop-up form, which includes the selectized list, the focus is stolen from the selectize list when the list's scrollbar is clicked/dragged.  Commenting-Out the draggable assignment allows the selectize list to work normally, including the scrollbar.

The odd thing is that I'm using the draggable component's handle feature to limit the dragging to a title area at the top of the pop-up form, that doesn't enclose the selectize list, which I thought would have caused the draggable click/drag to only affect the title area, but clearly this isn't the case.  With the draggable assignment not commented-out, the dragging feature does only happens using the title area, but the selectize list's scrollbar doesn't work when it is clicked.  However, commenting-out the assignment causes the list scrollbar to work as expected.

**Solution:** Besides finding another way to make the form draggable, I wanted to stick with the jQuery-UI library because I use it for other features. I found that instead of creating the draggable component on the form, I needed to create the component when the mouse moved over the form title and delete the component when the mouse moved away from the form title.  I tried simply enabling and disabling the component, but that didn't work.

Here is the link to the CodePen: https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/aazWwY.

```
<div id="songData"
     style="position: absolute; left: 626px; top: 8px; z-index: 99;
            width: 672px; min-height: 423px; max-height: 635px;
            padding: 0 28px 28px 28px; border: 5px double black;
            background-color: white; color: black;">
  <!-- **********************************************************************

       Prevent the songData 'form' area dragging when the mouse isn't over
       the songData Title.

       This prevents a problem with the selectize drop-down list that causes
       the list to loose focus when the options scrollbar is clicked.

       ****************************************************************** -->

  <div id="songDataTitle"
       style="margin-left: -28px; padding: 28px; height: 20px; width: 100%;
              text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;
              cursor: move;"
       onmouseover="songData_dragable( true );"
       onmouseout="songData_dragable( false );">
    Song Information Form
  </div>

  <script>
    function songData_dragable( mode ) {

      if( !mode  )

        $( '#songData' ).draggable( 'destroy' );

      else

        $( '#songData' ).draggable( { handle : '#songDataTitle' } );

      // End of if( !mode  ) ... else ...

    } // End of songData_dragable( mode ) function.
  </script>

<!-- rest of the web-page goes here -->
```